# Is there a way to close windows personalization window programatically?

Tags: c#

How can I close a single window of the explorer.exe process? I found a solution using `FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName)`

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName);

private void closeWindow()
{
    // retrieve the handler of the window  
    int iHandle = FindWindow("CabinetWClass", "Personalization");
    if (iHandle > 0)
    {
        // close    
    }  
}
```

That works, but how can I derive the used window name, which will be different if a different Windows language is used?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the exact thing you are trying to do?

Comment: close personalization window when it's opened

Comment: I understand that from question, why you want to do that?

Comment: I use `Process.Start(Path to theme)` to change user theme, but i don't wont to show him a personalization window